# gnome-terminal like terminal in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, terminal, cygwin, gnome-terminal

I'm running Cygwin in Windows XP. I find it quite handy, apart from it running in the default Windows Command Prompt.

Are there any alternatives to this? For example, is there a terminal that is like *gnome-terminal*? I would like something that allows me to double click, mouse drag to select text;  Ctrl+Shift+[XCV] to cut, copy and paste text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The favored terminal on Cygwin at the moment is mintty. I believe that it's part of the base install. If not, it's in the mintty package you can install from setup.exe.